# Returning a random name from a function to main

Tags: c

New to C and this site. I am trying to randomly select a name in an array of arrays in a function. Then return that random name to main where I can use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>     // For rand function

int  random_number(int, int);

char * random_name(char *);

int main(void)
{
char * main_pointer;

printf("\nIn main:\nmain_pointer = %s\n", main_pointer);

return 0;
}
char * random_name(char * MAIN_POINTER)
{
int x = random_number(0,7);

char random[7][5] =
{"0Sam", "1Sam", "3Sam", "4Sam", "5Sam", "6Sam", "7Sam"};

MAIN_POINTER = &random[x][0];

printf("In the function:\nrandom = %s\nMAIN_POINTER = %s\n", (&random[x][0]), MAIN_POINTER);

return MAIN_POINTER;

}
int random_number(int min, int max)
{
int roll;
int maximum = max - min;

srand(time(NULL));
roll = (rand() % maximum) + min;
return roll;
}
```

Sample run:

```
In the function:
random = 0Sam
MAIN_POINTER = 0Sam

In main:
main_pointer = Ø'Þ¿¦¼i·
```

As you can see it becomes garbage.

Comment: Your code doesn't call your function in `main`, so you need to fix your code to match the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int  random_number(int, int);
const char *random_name(void);

int main(void){
    const char * main_pointer;

    main_pointer = random_name();
    printf("\nIn main:\nmain_pointer = %s\n", main_pointer);

    return 0;
}
const char *random_name(void){
    int x = random_number(0,7);
    const char *random[7] =
        {"0Sam", "1Sam", "3Sam", "4Sam", "5Sam", "6Sam", "7Sam"};

    return random[x];
}
```

Comment: Thank you bluepixy, you're a genius. This code works and does what I want it to!

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with the code as posted, but lets start with this:

```
char * main_pointer;
```

This is always a bad thing to do, it leaves "main_pointer" as uninitialized. Your compiler should have told you this.

> test.c: In function ‘main’:
> test.c:12:7: warning: ‘main_pointer’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

If you're using GCC, then add the "-Wall" compiler option to get more diagnostic output, and always try to assign a default value to your variables, e.g.

```
char * main_pointer = NULL;
```

Next problem:

```
char * random_name(char * MAIN_POINTER)
....
MAIN_POINTER = &random[x][0];
```

While this is legal, I don't think it does what you are expecting. When you pass pointers as function arguments like this, the *address* the pointer is pointing to is passed and is stored in a new pointer variable. Any changes made are made to this new copy and when the function returns, they are lost.

```
char* test(char* in)
{
    in = in + 1;
    return in + 10;
}

....
    char* p = (char*)1000; // 'p' now points to memory location 1000.
    char* q = test(p);
    printf("p = %p, q = %q\n", p, q);
```

Will print:

> 1000
> 1011

Essentially, pointers work just like variables, in this case "in" was initialized to the same value as "p", the address "1000", when we added 1 to it, it was only the private variable "in" that was modified.

The only special feature of a pointer is that you can "dereference" it. If you wanted your "random_name" function to be able to alter the pointer main_pointer, you would need to pass the address of the pointer and dereference that:

```
void random_name(char** main_pointer) // address of the pointer
{
    ...
    (*main_pointer) = random[x];
}
```

Since the call to random_name is missing from your code, I can't tell if you were expecting to receive it like this:

```
main_pointer = random_name(main_pointer);
```

Doesn't seem like a lot of point passing it to the function in this case since you never actually use it.

Another problem your code is going to run into is that you are trying to use a pointer to hoist data from inside the scope of a function to something above it on the stack. This is dangerous. If you need data to persist or be visible outside of a function, it needs to either be declared in the global scope or given the "static" attribute.

```
const char* random_names[] = { "0Sam", "1Sam", "2Sam", ... };

// or

void random_name(const char** main_pointer)
{
    size_t x = random(0, 7);
    static const char* random_names[] = { "0Sam", "1Sam", "2Sam", ... };
    (*main_pointer) = random_names[x];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You never set the value for `main_pointer` in main() function, it just has a garbage address.

Comment: Isaach this is first error:, next error would be *"MAIN_POINTER points to a local object &random[x][0]; scope of and life of random[][] array is within random_name() function and you are returning address of local object that is illegal."* (include this also then code will be rectified)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to correct your program and it runs fine now.For the explanation,please see the comments inline your code.

Correct running code:

#include "stdio.h"

#include "stdlib.h"

#include "string.h"

#include "time.h"    // For rand function

int  random_number(int, int);

char * random_name(char *);

int main(void)

{

```
    char * main_pointer=NULL; /*Uni:Initialize this pointer to NULL*/

    /*Uni: You have still not allocated any memory/storage for main_pointer 
      and the main_pointer basically points NOWHERE at this point,so 
      printing its value doesnot make any sense here */

    /*Uni:Allocate memory for main_pointer*/
    main_pointer = (char *)malloc(5*sizeof(char));
    /*Uni:Call the random_name function to get the random Name*/
    random_name(main_pointer);

    /*Uni:Now print mainpointer */
    printf("\nIn main:\nmain_pointer = %s\n", main_pointer);

    return 0;}
```

char * random_name(char * MAIN_POINTER)

{

```
   int x = random_number(0,7);

    char random[7][5] =
    {"0Sam", "1Sam", "2Sam", "3Sam", "4Sam","5Sam","6Sam"};


/*Uni: When you declare any Array, the array name itself is a pointer,
  so here &random is a double pointer 
  Note: If you want to return only the VALUE of nth string,
  then simply writing random[x] would suffice
  random[0]: First string
  random[1]: Second string
  .
  .
  .
  random [6]: 7th string
  So,we can access any string at nth position as random[n];*/


 /*Commenting this as here double char pointer is being assigned to
  single char pointer*/
 /*MAIN_POINTER = &random[x][0];*/

 /*Uni:Copying string STARTING  at Random[x] position.Each row of 
   random_Array holds a string of length 5 characters*/

/*Range check ,so that we don`t read out of bound array */ 
if(0<=x<=6)
{
    printf("Uni:Value of x %d, Random Name %s",x,random[x]);
    strncpy(MAIN_POINTER,random[x],5);
}

/*Uni: No need of returning pointer here,as we have copied 
  the string value (Random   name) in MAIN_POINTER already*/
 return MAIN_POINTER;}
```

int random_number(int min, int max)

{

```
int roll;

int maximum = max - min;


srand(time(NULL)); 

roll = (rand() % maximum) + min;

return roll;
```

}

Comment: `srand()` should only be called __once__, typically in `main()`. If you are going to correct the code you should fix that call to `srand()` inside the `random_number()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The variable **random[7][5]** is local to the function **random_name**. The variable will be expire/not available once the function returns..

In your case returning a pointer to the variable **random** will result in **undefined behaviour**

**Solution**:

1) Moving the variable **random** to global
2) Moving the variable **random** to main function and passing the variable as argument